# Tic Tac Toe - Javascript: show current player nickname

Tags: javascript

i'm a beginner in javascript. So I have a local multiplayer Tic Tac Toe Game and i want to get players nicknames from the two inputs and display in game by current player turn/ winner nickname.
I can access from console the values stored in p1 and p2 (p1.name, p1.val and p2.name, p2.val) but i don't know how to call them in setTurnIndicator function and check winnner.
I tried to store them in local storage and get them but it doesn't work.

```
// Multiplayer Options
let ps = document.getElementById('btn');
let c1 = document.getElementsByName('characP1');
let c2 = document.getElementsByName('characP2');
let msg = document.getElementById('message');
let char1;
let char2;

function Player(name, val) {
    this.name = name;
    this.val = val;
}
for (i = 0; i < c1.length; i++) {
    c1[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            this.value == 'X' ? c2[1].checked = true : c2[0].checked = true;
            char1 = this.value;
            char2 = this.value == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';
        }
    });
}
for (i = 0; i < c2.length; i++) {
    c2[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            this.value == 'X' ? c1[1].checked = true : c1[0].checked = true;
            char2 = this.value
            char1 = this.value == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';
        }
    });
}
ps.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let player1 = document.getElementById('p1').value;
    let player2 = document.getElementById('p2').value;
    p1 = new Player(player1, char1);
    p2 = new Player(player2, char2);
    if (p1.name && p1.val && p2.name && p2.val) {
        msg.innerHTML = p1.name + ' : ' + p1.val + '<br />' + p2.name + ' : ' + p2.val;
    } else {
        msg.innerHTML = 'Please fill all input fields';
    }
    // return playerOne, playerTwo;
    // window.localStorage.setItem('nume1', p1.name);
    // window.localStorage.setItem('nume2', p2.name);
});

// Hide Players Options
function hidePlayersOptions() {
    let x = document.getElementById("mpOptions");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
    let y = document.getElementById("game");
    if (y.style.display === "none") {
        y.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        y.style.display = "block";
      }
  }

// Multiplayer Game Logic
/* Tic-Tac-Toe functions */
let TicTacToe = {
    /* initialize the Tic-Tac-Toe variables */
    init: function() {
        this.symbols = [`X`, `O`];
        this.name = [window.localStorage.getItem('nume1'), window.localStorage.getItem('nume2')];
        this.squares = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".square"));
        this.turnIndicator = document.querySelector(".turnIndicator");
        this.button = document.querySelector(".newGame");
        this.board = document.querySelector(".board");
        // square positions in which you can get 3-in-a-row
        this.winningSets = [
            // horizontal sets
            [0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8],
            // vertical sets
            [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8],
            // diagonal sets
            [0,4,8], [2,4,6]
        ];
        // add click event listeners to squares and button
        this.addEventListeners();
        // reset the game
        this.newGame();
    },

    // add click event listeners to squares and button
    addEventListeners: function() {
        let ttt = this;
        // for each square, add a click listener which will call "play()"
        this.squares.forEach(function(x) {
            x.addEventListener("click",function() {
                ttt.play(this);
            }, false)
        })
        // when the new game button is clicked, call "newGame()"
        this.button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            ttt.newGame();
        }, false);
    },

    // reset the game
    newGame: function() {
        // set player to first player (X)
        this.activePlayer = 0;
        // reset the game over variable
        this.gameOver = false;
        // remove all X and O classes from every square
        this.squares.forEach(function (x) {
            x.classList.remove(TicTacToe.symbols[0]);
            x.classList.remove(TicTacToe.symbols[1]);
        })
        // remove gameOver class from board if it exists
        this.board.classList.remove("gameOver");
        // set the turn indicator (X's turn)
        this.setTurnIndicator();
    },

    // set the turn indicator to indicate whose turn it is
    setTurnIndicator: function() {
        this.turnIndicator.innerText = this.symbols[this.name[this.activePlayer]] + "'s turn."
        // this.turnIndicator.innerText = this.symbols["window.localStorage.getItem('nume1')"] + "'s turn."
        // this.turnIndicator.innerText = this.symbols[window.localStorage.getItem('nume1')[this.activePlayer]];
    },

    play: function(el) {
        // make sure that the square is not filled
        if (!this.gameOver && el.classList.length == 1) {
            // set the contents to your player's symbol
            el.classList.add(this.symbols[this.activePlayer]);
            // check if you won
            if (this.checkWin()) {
                // set the game text to display the winner
                this.turnIndicator.innerText = this.symbols[this.activePlayer] + " wins!";
                // call the game over function
                this.endGame();
            }
            // check if there is a draw
            else if (this.checkDraw()) {
                // set the game text to say it is a draw
                this.turnIndicator.innerText = "It's a draw!";
                // call the game over function
                this.endGame();
            }
            // go to the next player's turn
            else {
                // change the turn (0 -> 1 or 1 -> 0)
                this.activePlayer = 1 - this.activePlayer;
                // set the turn indicator text
                this.setTurnIndicator();
            }
        }
    },

    // check if current player won
    checkWin: function() {
        let ttt = this;
        // if for any of the winning sets,
        // every square in the set is filled with
        // the current player's symbol, return true
        // otherwise, return false
        return this.winningSets.some(function (x) {
            return x.every(function(i) {
                return Array.from(ttt.squares[i].classList).indexOf(ttt.symbols[ttt.activePlayer]) > -1;
            })
        })
    },

    // check if there is a draw
    checkDraw: function() {
        // return true if every square
        // has more than 1 class (is filled)
        // otherwise, return false
        return this.squares.every(function (x) {
            return x.classList.length > 1;
        })
    },

    // set the game over variable and board class when the game ends
    endGame: function() {
        this.gameOver = true;
        this.board.classList.add("gameOver");
    }
}

// call the init() function of TicTacToe when the page loads
TicTacToe.init();
```

https://codepen.io/sebastian-mihai-ciuc/pen/LYmoMrj

Comment: not sure its the best solution, but why is local storage not working? If you simply save the name to local storage, you should be able to access it at any time.

Comment: I saved my values ​​to local storage, but I can't figure out how to use them in my code.

Comment: var name1 = localStorage['nume1'];